# Is there a syntax only for destructuring assignment in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

For example, `#each` syntax is convenient because destructuring assignment occurs simultaneously.

So I created and wrote an array of 1 even if it is not an array.

```
  <div>{ item.aaa }</div>
  <div>{ item.bbb }</div>
  <div>
    <div>{ item.ccc.ddd }</div>
    <div>{ item.ccc.eee }</div>
  </div>
```

to

```
  {#each [item] as { aaa, bbb, ccc: { ddd, eee }} }
    <div>{ aaa }</div>
    <div>{ bbb }</div>
    <div>
      <div>{ ddd }</div>
      <div>{ eee }</div>
    </div>
  {/each}
```

Is this okay?

Or is there a cleaner way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring is just a standard JS functionality, it can be used in the script without `{#each}`. The only difference is that the markup is reactive by default.

If you need to destructure [reactively](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive), you have to use parentheses in the script:

```js
// Not reactive
const { aaa, bbb, ccc: { ddd, eee } } = item;
// Reactive
$: ({ aaa, bbb, ccc: { ddd, eee } } = item);
```

You also can destructure in [`@const` directives](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-tags#const) in markup, though they are not allowed in every context.

```html
{@const { aaa, bbb, ccc: { ddd, eee } } = item}
```

> `{@const}` must be the immediate child of `{#if}`, `{:else if}`, `{:else}`, `{#each}`, `{:then}`, `{:catch}`, `<svelte:fragment>` or `<Component>`